# Switch style property on element hover using JQuery/Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, hover, reactjs

I made a mistake on my original question (my code was not working after I changed), so I changed this

I create some **radial-element** dynamically at father component, always pairs (element, element-hover)

```
render: function() {
    var gradientID = "gradient" + this.props.c.id;
    var gradientID_hover = gradientID +"-hover"

    return (
        <g className={this.props.c.id}> 
            <defs>
                <radialGradient id={gradientID} fx="50%" fy="50%" r="65%" spreadMethod="pad">
                  <stop offset="0%"   stopColor={this.props.c.color[0]} stopOpacity="0.8"/>
                  <stop offset="100%" stopColor={this.props.c.color[1]} stopOpacity="1" />
                </radialGradient>

                <radialGradient id={gradientID_hover}   fx="50%" fy="50%" r="65%" spreadMethod="pad">
                  <stop offset="0%"   stopColor={this.props.c.color[3]} stopOpacity="0.8"/>
                  <stop offset="100%" stopColor={this.props.c.color[4]} stopOpacity="1" />
                </radialGradient>
            </defs>
        </g>
    )
}
```

And at son element, I use that id on **path** element, as following:

```
render: function() {
    var fillURL = "url(#"+this.props.gradientID+")";
    return (
        <g className={this.props.country.id}>
            <path stroke="#000000" fill={fillURL} d={this.props.country.path} strokeOpacity="0.25" strokeWidth="1.5"></path>
        </g>    
    );
}
```

How can I change fill property of path on hover? I Tryed something like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var element = this.getDOMNode().firstChild;
    $(element).hover(function(){
        element.backup = element.style.fill;
        element.style.fill = element.backup+"-hover";

    }, function(){
        element.style.fill = element.backup;
    });
},
```

And did not work because that property contais whole url "url(#gradientID)" and with hover it will be 
"url(#gradientID)-hover".

I know I can parse old property to new be "url(#gradientID-hover)", but I want if there are a better way to do this

Comment: And you're unable to change two style attributes in the same `:hover` CSS rule because why?

Comment: I failed to explain this, is because I create RadialGradient elements dynamically using ID, and when I set "fill" property I pass that ID

Answer (score 0):

```
$('yourID').hover(function(){ $('targetID').css('targetAttr','attrVal') });
```

Have you tried something like this?

Comment: Can you explain a litte what a single function on hover with .css() will do? 

And sorry, I missed an important information, see my edit. Thanks